# Basic Lua problem - A if statement nested in for loop

Tags: lua

I am an amateur in Lua, l wrote this code but fail to compile, l have checked the structure of the syntax and found that it was a match, so l really do not know what is wrong, it says that 
18: 'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 16) near 'startFishing'
but why should l do that?????
BTW startFishing is another function that l defined previously in the same file.

```
function detectSuccess()
    local count = 0;
    for x = 448, 1140, 140 do
        color = getColor(x, 170);
        if color == 0xffffff then 
            return false
            startFishing()
        else
            return true
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: `startFishing()` after `return`??

Answer (score 6):

Formatting code correctly we have ....

```
function detectSuccess()
   local count = 0;
    for x = 448, 1140, 140 do
        color = getColor(x, 170);
        if color == 0xffffff then 
            return false
            startFishing()
        else
            return true
        end
    end
end

detectSuccess()
```

The `startFishing()` statement is dangling.  syntactically the only thing that can come after return, is the else or end.

That is the complaint from the lua parser.

From [lua : programming in lua 4.4](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.4.html)

> For syntactic reasons, a break or return can appear only as the last statement of a block (in other words, as the last statement in your chunk or just before an end, an else, or an until).

If you want `startFishing` to be called, it needs to be before the return. e.g.

```
function detectSuccess()
   local count = 0;
    for x = 448, 1140, 140 do
        color = getColor(x, 170);
        if color == 0xffffff then 
            startFishing() -- moved before the return
            return false
        else
            return true
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a statement in the same block after a `return`. I guess you mean this instead:

```
if color == 0xffffff then 
   startFishing()
   return false
else
   return true
end
```

Indenting your code will help you seeing syntax problems.